# XLL: Convert xloper to vector<double>

Tags: c++, excel, vector, double, xll

How can I convert a xloper or xloper12 to a vector?

It's a straightforward question, I don't see what other details to give.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a bit of a pain but here's some skeleton code to get you started.

Suppose you have an `LPXLOPER12 lpxloper` (or the older `LPXLOPER` type). You get the type using

`DWORD type = lpxloper->xltype & ~(xlbitXLFree|xlbitDLLFree);`

The only non-scalar type is `xltypeMulti`. If you have such a type then you can use

```
auto rows = lpxloper->val.array.rows;
auto columns = lpxloper->val.array.columns;
```

to set up your `std::vector` and use the following to extract the elements:

```
for (decltype(rows) i = 0; i < rows; ++i){
    for (decltype(columns) j = 0; j < columns; ++j){
        /*element i, j is*/ = lpxloper->val.array.lparray + j + (i * columns);
    }
}
```

I've used `auto` and `decltype` so this works with XLOPER and XLOPER12. The row index types differ.